# Do in-process/same appDomain Remoting TCP calls go via the network card?

Tags: c#, tcp

.... or does .Net do something special if it determines the TCP call isn't necessary i.e. when the Remoting client and server are running in the same appDomain?

Comment: Why are you using remoting if it is in the same AppDomain? Does not compute!

Comment: In case the client wants/needs to run the different components on different machine or in different processes. I need it to work the same in-appDomain, in-process(diff appDomains) and across machines.

Comment: Ahh ok :)  Try use WireShark in that case.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that if you're connecting to the loopback interface (127.0.01 or ::1) the calls will not get as far as the network card. If you're using an IP address assigned to the network card, I suspect the traffic will go through the network card (though whether the network card will make any shortcuts compared to actual traffic leaving the interface, I don't know).